# Is there an alternative to slice method in angular pagination which retains the full array?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let company of (companies | filter:filterText | slice:lowValue:highValue ); let ix=index;" routerLink="/profile" [queryParams] ="{id: company.id, page:pageIndex}" >
        
        <div mat-list-icon>
            <img width="25" src="{{ getCompanyLogo(company.domain) }}" />
        </div>
        <span fxFlex="10"></span>
        <a mat-line mat-line color="primary">{{ company.name }}</a>
        <p mat-line></p>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    </mat-list-item>

lowValue = pageSize*pageIndex
highValue = lowValue + pageSize
```

And this works.

However, the problem that I'm facing right now is after I added the `filter` for filtering data from the array. When I'm on the first page which only shows 10 items, I can search using a keyword in the entire array. But soon as I hit next page, the array gets sliced and a new array with only the items to display is returned. And now, when I search for an item, all it searches for is the new `sliced` array - so it may not find what I'm searching for and returns empty, even though the item exists in the original array.

What's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the pipes and instead listen to the events when your filterText / pageIndex changes.

You didn't show us much of your code, so I'll run with some assumptions.

I assume all your records are filtered / paged localaly and the `companies` is the local property holding ALL the companies. You can do something along the lines of:

```
// Define a new property - and assign initial value of a shallow clone of the initial array.
// Use this property in the ngFor without the pipes.
displayedRecords: Company[] = [...this.companies];

// All the other stuff you already have
...

// New method - hook it up to when filterText OR pageIndex changes
private filterRecords(): void {
    // Apply filter logic from your custom pipe - below is an example.
    let filtered: Company[];
    
    if (this.filterText !== undefined && this.filterText.length > 0) {
        filtered = this.companies.filter(c => c.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.filterText.toLowerCase()));
    } else {
        filtered = [...this.companies];
    }
    
    const lowValue = this.pageSize * this.pageIndex
    const highValue = lowValue + this.pageSize

    this.displayedRecords = filtered.slice(lowValue, highValue);
}
```

Comment: This is a really good alternative solution. I like this. I'll give this a try and come back with comments. Thank you for sharing this idea.

Comment: This is great!! With some minor modification, it worked perfectly. The part I had to modify was to init `lowValue` and `highValue` with 0 and 10, and then get the `lowValue` and` highValue` from `pagination` inside `else`. Otherwise, it was slicing start and end position which doesn't exist in the array.

Comment: for `[...this.companies]`,+1.. I learnt about the shallow copy